# Is there a way in Javascript to only get the values from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to add a 'Search' feature to my project. What I'd like to do is search only the values of a JSON object so that my regular expression doesn't try to match the property names when I evaluate the members of the object.

Consider the following example:

```
var myObj = { 
  'FirstName': 'Joe', 
  'LastName': 'Jones',
  'Age': 35,
  'Address': {
    'City': 'Boise',
    'State': 'Idaho'
  }
};
var myObjValues = JSON.stringify(myObj);
// result: "{"FirstName":"Joe","LastName":"Jones", etc... }"
```

However, what I'd like to get is a single string with all values flatted to a single string separated by a space (or a comma, or a semi-colon, or a tab) like this:

```
// result: "Joe Jones 35 Boise Idaho"
```

I will never know what the object is. In my example above I'm using names and addresses, but the object could be anything with any level of nested objects below it. I only want the deepest attributes that are strings and numbers.

Is there a way to do this using the JSON object? Is there a library that does this somewhere, I thought about writing my own function to strip these values out and build the string myself, but didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks in advance for any tips or pointers!

Comment: A quick for..in loop should do the trick.

Comment: Note the comment in wong2's answer: **"I'm wondering if the order of values matters?"** Because, if it does, then ... well you're up a creek.

Comment: I just updated my question to indicate that I have no idea what the object is, nor do i know how many levels deep the nested objects will be. I'm not a Javascript guru, so if there is a library out there that does this, I'd much prefer to use it. Thanks for the tip on the for loop, but my requirement is a little more involved I think... (?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var vals = Object.keys(myObj).map(function(k) { return myObj[k]; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ezQuv/

And use `.join(' ')` if you wanted a string result.

---

For your updated question with nested objects, you can do this...

```
var vals = function getVals(o) {
    return Object.keys(o)
                 .map(function(k) {
                        if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object')
                            return getVals(o[k]);
                        else
                            return o[k];
                    }).join(' ');
}(myObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKbMS/

---

Or if you like conditional operators over if/else statements, like this...

```
var vals = function getVals(o) {
    return Object.keys(o)
              .map(function(k) {
                  return o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' ? getVals(o[k]) : o[k];
              }).join(' ');
}(myObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKbMS/1/

---

- [MDN patch for `Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatiblity)
- [MDN patch for `Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity)

Comment: +1 for being nice and "functional". If only there was a way to drop the `function/return` syntax fluff ;-) Also, it should be noted that  `Object.keys` is [new in] ECMAScript 5th Edition.

Comment: @pst: I think some nicer lambda syntax may be coming with ES6, but `Object.keys` is ES5 specific, but then so is `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: This answer was part of my court ordered community service. :-P

Comment: How is the browser compatibility of this?

Comment: @wong2: It's perfectly compatible with all the right browsers, and none of the wrong ones. ;-)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that my object might have other nested objects attached to it (see my updated question). Thanks for the simplest approach yet! I love the functional approach!! +1

Comment: @Luc: I updated my answer. It assumes that the only nested objects will be using plain objects as in your question.

Comment: Luc: You're welcome, but please do consider the comments from @pst, wong2 about browser compatibility. If you're supporting legacy browsers, you'd need to apply patches, which can be found at http://developer.mozilla.org . I'll add links to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
var myObj = { 
  'FirstName': 'Joe', 
  'LastName': 'Jones',
  'Age': 35,
  'City': 'Boise',
  'State': 'Idaho'
};
var myObjValues = [];
for(var n in myObj)
    myObjValues.push(myObj[n]);
myObjValues = myObjValues.join(' ');
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because there could be a lot of nested objects below this object with other nested objects. I just want the values of the deepest objects properties. Perhaps I could use your code with a bit of recursion and type checking, but perhaps there's another solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard function for this.

you can use underscore's [values](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#values) function, this is the code:

```
var values = _.values( JSON.stringify(myObj) ),
    values_str = values.join(" ");
```

UPDATE:

I'm wondering if the order of values matters?

Comment: Link to library/documentation, please.

Comment: Thanks @wong2! No the order does NOT matter. Great idea using underscore library. However, I'm not currently using the underscore library in my (enormous) project and would like to avoid it if possible. Is there an equivalent method in the jQuery library? I guess I could strip out just the 'values()' method, but... Curious... +1